# Is there a difference between "tief" and "niedrig"?

Tags: difference, adjective, standard-german, learning

From what I see, *tief* means *deep* while *niedrig* means *low*. However, I have seen some websites claim that *tief* can also be used as *low*. Is it situational or geographical? Is one more common than the other?

Comment: Wiktionary lists both "deep" and "low" as possible translations for "tief". They give the example: Du hast das Bild zu tief gehängt. ― You hung the picture too low. There is a difference, since you'd never translate "niedrig" as "deep. It's just that German draws the line at a different place than English. This kind of thing is common with different languages.

Comment: @RDBury isn't that the answer? (even when assuming that this might be closed with "use of dictionary"... though I still understand asking about these differences)?

Comment: Thank you for answering! Could I use tief and niedrig interchangeably when in the context of low? Using the example "Du hast das Bild zu tief gehängt", could I also say "Du hast das Bild zu niedrig gehängt"? Would they have the same meaning/both sound correct?

Comment: @planetmaker - Henning Kockerbeck's answer had a lot of information that I didn't know. I was just trying to point out some possible issues with the question.

Comment: Yes, it does. It is also an insightful answer to me, thus +1

Comment: There are definitely regional differences. For instance, Germans use "niedrig" for the figurative sense, e.g. "Hohe Auslastung" vs. "Niedrige/geringe Auslastung". Swiss German uses "Hohe" vs. "Tiefe Auslastung" instead.

Answer (score 3):

It's mostly a question of the base line. As you've pointed out, "tief" means something like "deep", while "niedrig" means something like "low":

> Das Schiffswrack liegt tief unter der Meeresoberfläche.
> The ship wreck lies deep below the sea's surface.

> Die Wolken hängen sehr niedrig über der Wiese.
> The clouds are hanging very low above the meadow.

So "tief" is typically *below* some base line, while "niedrig" is *above* some base line (not much above, but above).

Regarding your picture example from the comments, you can imagine multiple implicit base lines:

> Du hast das Bild zu niedrig (über dem Boden) aufgehängt.
> You hung the picture too low (above the floor).

> Du hast das Bild zu tief (unterhalb der Sichtlinie) aufgehängt.
> You hung the picture too deep (below the line of sight).

The latter example would probably sound strange in English, but is completely fine in German.